# javascript method not compiling in IE but works fine when running debug

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this javascript method that I altered from an existing script that I found online that should rotate showing an indefinite number of `'.testimonial'` divs. The script works fine in chrome and firefox, but doesn't compile in internet explorer, unless you use f12 to start the debugging of the script. **Is there a better way to write this script?** I have looked online for ideas but haven't been able to find anything. I imagine that the issue is with the `console.log(testimonialCount);` statement, but am unsure of a better way to write it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
//rotate testimonials script
jQuery('.testimonial').hide();

var testimonialCount = $('.testimonial').length;
console.log(testimonialCount );
var currentItem = 0;
var timeout;
timeout = window.setTimeout((function(){switchDiv();}));    

switchDiv = function() {
    if (currentItem == testimonialCount - 1) {
        jQuery('.testimonial').eq(testimonialCount - 1).hide();
        currentItem = 0;
        jQuery('.testimonial').eq(0).fadeIn();
        timeout = window.setTimeout((function(){switchDiv();}),7000);
    }
    else {
        jQuery('.testimonial').eq(currentItem).hide();
        currentItem = currentItem + 1;
        jQuery('.testimonial').eq(currentItem).fadeIn();
        timeout = window.setTimeout((function(){switchDiv();}),7000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with "compilation"; Javascript is not compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the IE developer tools are not open, there is no `console` object.
Therefore, calling `console.log()` throws an error.

To prevent that, you can check `if ('console' in window)` and make your own dummy console (or just don't log anything) if it isn't.

Comment: Thanks. The `console.log(testimonialCount );` wasn't really doing anything in the script so I just took it out and it compiled just fine. Thanks for helping me understand how the console works.

Answer (score 2):

A few notes:

Add this to the very top of your script:

```
window.console = console || { 'log' : function(){} };
```

This defines `window.console` in case it isn't. Doesn't do anything except avoid errors.

Next take out the parenthesis around your timeout functions:

```
timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){ switchDiv(); },7000);
```

... or just simplify further:

```
timeout = window.setTimeout(switchDiv,7000);
```

I am being picky here but:

`currentItem = currentItem + 1;` is the same as `currentItem++;`

Another picky thing `window.setTimeout` is the same as `setTimeout`.